# Load "on the fly" code with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, famo.us

I'm trying to create an online interactive js programming test-bed. I have a code window and a target iframe where the code gets loaded to execute. I wrap the code in html and load it into the iframe. The problem is that the code I want to be testing is normally loaded via requirejs using a data-main parameter. It appears that the code needs to be loaded from a separate file so that I can't include it in the html itself.

What works but doesn't help me is creating a file on the server to use as the target of the data-main parameter and sending html to the iframe that requires requirejs and then loads my code.

html:

```
<html>
 ....
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="src/requireConfigTest"></script>
 ....
</html>
```

contents of requireConfigTest.js:

```
/*globals require*/
require.config({
    shim: {

    },
    paths: {
        famous: 'lib/famous',
        requirejs: 'lib/requirejs/require',
        almond: 'lib/almond/almond',
        'famous-polyfills': 'lib/famous-polyfills/index'
    }
});
// this is the injection point where the dynamic code starts
define(function (require,exports,module) {
    var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
    var Surface = require("famous/core/Surface");

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

    var surface = new Surface({
        size: [100, 100],
        content: "Hello World",
        classes: ["red-bg"],
        properties: {
            textAlign: "center",
            lineHeight: "20px"
        }
    });
    alert('hi');
    mainContext.add(surface);

});
//this is the end of the dynamic code
```

This requires writing the dynamic code back to the server, not a reasonable solution. I'm trying to implement something like this...

html:

```
<html>
 ....
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*globals require*/
require.config({
    shim: {

    },
    paths: {
        famous: 'lib/famous',
        requirejs: 'lib/requirejs/require',
        almond: 'lib/almond/almond',
        'famous-polyfills': 'lib/famous-polyfills/index'
    }
});
// this is the injection point where the dynamic code starts
define(function (require,exports,module) {
    var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
    var Surface = require("famous/core/Surface");

    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

    var surface = new Surface({
        size: [100, 100],
        content: "Hello World",
        classes: ["red-bg"],
        properties: {
            textAlign: "center",
            lineHeight: "20px"
        }
    });
alert('hi');
    mainContext.add(surface);

});
//this is the end of the dynamic code
</script>
```

This fails with the message:

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function
>   (require, exports, module) {...

My hope is to either find a way to reformat the code above in the second script tag or find a way to pass the actual contents of requireConfigTest.js via data-main instead of passing the name of the file to load.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not actually defining a module with your `define` call, you could just use `require`:

```
require(["famous/core/Engine", "famous/core/Surface"], function (Engine, Surface) {
    var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
    // Etc...
```

You can think of `define` as being a `require` call which *additionally* defines a module. The way you are using `define` it is defining a module that does not have a name because you did not give it a name (which is generally the right thing to do) but it is not loaded from a `.js` file. When you don't give a name to a module as the first argument of `define`, RequireJS assigns a name from the `.js` file it loads the module from.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `require` schedules its callback for execution right away. (The callback is not *executed* right away but it *scheduled* for execution right away.) Whereas `define` does not schedule anything. It just records the callback and then when a `require` call (or something equivalent) requires it, the callback is executed.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. My code is dynamic so the require elements will vary, but the reformatting the call will be simple mechanics. Thanks again. Rich.